# Running into error when attempting to printf() different arrays of structures

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, printf

I am trying to print out my 10 different arrays of my struct songList[10]. I have used the debugger and have confirmed each input requested is being stored at each index properly, the issue seems to lie within my printing function. I am getting an "Exception thrown at 0x0003187E in mini1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC." Error when it tries to loop through at print the strings at the index requested. Any help would be great thanks!  Also I am trying to print each songArtist and songTitle starting at index 0 of the songList[10] array. It should print both left aligned and with 35 characters being used for each.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#pragma warning(disable:4996)

int getSongInfo(struct songInfo *pFillInfo, char *artistName, char *songName);
int printSongInfo(songInfo *songList[]);

struct songInfo {

    char *songArtist;
    char *songTitle;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct songInfo *fillPtr, songList[10];
    fillPtr = &songList[0];

    char tempArtist[30][10];
    char tempSong[30][10];

    int i = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int arrayCounter = 0;
    while (counter != 10)
    {
        printf("Please enter the artist name: ");
        fgets(tempArtist[counter], sizeof(tempArtist[counter]), stdin);
        printf("Please enter the song name: ");
        fgets(tempSong[counter], sizeof(tempSong[counter]), stdin);

        getSongInfo(&fillPtr[arrayCounter], tempArtist[counter], tempSong[counter]);

        printf("Song and Artist Captured! \n");
        counter++;
        arrayCounter++;
    }

    printSongInfo(&fillPtr);
}

int getSongInfo(struct songInfo *pFillInfo, char *artistName, char *songName)
{
    pFillInfo->songArtist = (char*)malloc(strlen(artistName) + 1);
    pFillInfo->songTitle = (char*)malloc(strlen(songName) + 1);

    strcpy(pFillInfo->songArtist, artistName);
    strcpy(pFillInfo->songTitle, songName);



    return 1;
}

int printSongInfo(songInfo *songList[])
{
    int counter = 0;

    while (counter != 10)
    {
        printf("%-35s", songList[counter]->songArtist);
        printf("%-35s\n", songList[counter]->songTitle);
        counter++;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of returning a value from `getSongInfo` and `printSongInfo`? Just declare them as void.

Comment: That said, you're being deceptive to your compiler. Just because you populate `fillPtr` with the base address of an array of concrete objects, then pass the address of that pointer to a function expecting an array *of pointers* doesn't magically end up working. Ultimately you passing the address of *a* pointer; not a sequence of pointers. You "fixed" the error you were no-doubt getting by passing the address of `fillPtr`. All that does is hide the problem.

Comment: RocktheFries, Looks like you are compiling with a C++ compiler rather than C.

Comment: `printSongInfo` accesses out of bounds, you pass address of a single pointer but access it as if you passed an array of pointers. It should be `int printSongInfo(songInfo *songList)` and you pass `fillPtr` for the argument

Comment: Also `songInfo` is not defined, this code should fail to compile (if you are actually using a C compiler)

Comment: also it is not clear why you declared an array of 30 temporary artists when you only need 1 temporary string at a time

Comment: @M.M thank you, using your comments I figured out the Issue!